# Devise: Getting unique users via subdomain scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have an application using Devise for authentication with different accounts based on subdomain.

How can I separate Devise users and make e-mail only unique per subdomain scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :subdomain
```

In Rails 3:

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :scope => :subdomain
```

In migration:

```
add_index :users, [:subdomain, :email], :unique => true
```

Comment: Thanks :) But how to get the login to know which subdomain you pass to the login page/controller?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem.  The login shouldn't care if the login is unique, only when a login is saved to the database.  As for how do get Devise to save logins using a subdomain field, I don't know.

Comment: Okay – it was the Devise login part I was wondering how to do. Thanks for your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

scope need to be subdomain_id ( Cannot visit Subdomain , when using :scope => :subdomain )

validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :scope => :subdomain_id